Using custom guards result in Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exists
While I am testing out custom Auth guard with the following code, I got the error below.
> use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
> Auth::guard("my_custom_guard")
= Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard {#5359}
> Auth::guard("my_custom_guard")->attempt([])
   BadMethodCallException  Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.

My config/auth.php
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'members',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
        'my_custom_guard' => [
            'driver' => 'my_custom_driver',
        ],
    ],

I know that setting defaults guard can solve this problem, as some previous answers suggested.  However, I want to use any auth guard whenever necessary, that's what custom guard is used for, isn't it?
So other than updating defaults value, are there any way to use custom guard?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Update 9/8/2024: forgot to put this up:
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 */
public function boot(): void
{
    Auth::viaRequest('custom-token', function (Request $request) {
        // whatever auth way I want.  Example below:
        // return User::where('token', (string) $request->token)->first();
    });
}


Whenever you use attempt() in your application that corresponding route should be auth middleware(either default or your custmo one) protected. Are you sure you have assigned middleware to the the routes ? If this is the case then the answer I have posted below might not solve your problem. This vital  point I just noticed . Please reply

Also attempt() is only vailable on SessionGuard. So make sure your custom guard using session not API token.Check the link https://laravel.com/api/11.x/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_attempt

@Subha Thank you.  I notice the attempt() and validate() function as well.  And there is no middleware: The error I got is coming from php artisan tinker.  The objective I want is to validate a user in my own term, no middleware, using the Auth library.  I am referencing to this link.

You have defined it (i.e. guards) incorrectly. Also you need to defined it's respective providers that is missing in your code.
Do this changes in config/app.php...
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
        'my_custom_guard' => [
            'driver' => 'session', //you can change it accordingly
            'provider' => 'custom_guard', //you need to map this with `providers` array
        ],
    ],

And then you also need to define your providers array accordingly like this.
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

         'custom_guard' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',  //you can change it as well accordingly
             'table' => App\Models\CustomGuard::class,
         ],
    ],


Thanks for update.  And I thought about it also.  However according to this it seems that I don't need to define a provider.  And that's the reason why I want to use custom guard: I want to authenticate use in my own term.
